# Is it dangerous to publically show my chrome extension ID?

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

So i have built an chrome extension with manifest v3. Since it adds some images into the DOM, i wrote a line similar to this:

```
let imageSource = "chrome-extension://{id}/ExtensionImages/image.png";
```

I'm thinking about posting the extension on GitHub, but i don't know if showing the extension id publically on the source code could generate security issues for my extension or even for my computer.

I understand that there are probably better ways to retrieve an image with manifest without using the id, but even if i were to repace this line, anyone could still see my commit history and get the extension id.

Comment: Anyone can view your extension ID simply by installing it, going to `chrome://extensions`, clicking your extension, then scrolling to the "ID" section. So short answer: no. Long answer: nooooooooooooo.

Comment: @code is correct.. the ID is public already... making it more public will not change anything. Not dangerous at all

Comment: It is not dangerous at all, but you can still use `let ImageSource = chrome.runtime.getUrl('ExtensionImages/image.png')` which doesn't need your extension's id to be explicitly declared.

Comment: getUrl should be getURL